# Read store certificates in Windows Server 2019 with Asp.net and c #

Tags: c#, asp.net, x509certificate

Asp.net and c #. I just have to read the list of the current user's Personal certificates. If I use this code on the development computer it works, if I use it on the server with Windows 2019 and IIS 10, the archive looks empty, but I see a certificate that I have installed. (I am logged into the server as administrator)
I don't understand why this happens.

```
using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
{
 store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
 X509Certificate2Collection aCert = store.Certificates;
 aCert.Count; //WAS 34 ON MY PC, 0 ON SERVER 2019
}
```

Comment: If the application pool of IIS is not running under your user, it's normal the store is empty.
Consider using CurrentMachine, and store the certificate in the CurrentMachine\My location

Comment: @Preben Huybrechts. While you were writing it I was doing it and it works. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Your initial code could also have worked if you opened the certificate manager using the credentials of the user of the application pool and added the certificate on that user's store.

Answer (score 0):

I changed from StoreName.My to StoreName.Root and everything is fine.
I did everything as an Administrator

Comment: I would suggest you, in shake of completness, editing your answer and adding a note to make sure the user running the application pool is granted permission to the certificate. Forgetting that is sometimes a bit of a headache.

Comment: I have installed the certificate as Administrator and have not changed anything else. I add it to the answer